# MongoError: Document failed validation because of regex pattern?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I get a 'MongoError: Document failed validation' when I try to apply a regex verification on a phone field in a form :

```
db.createCollection("customers", {
       validator: {
          $jsonSchema: {
             bsonType: "object",
             required: [ "Email", "Phone"],
          properties: {
   Email: {
           bsonType: "string",
           pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}$",
           description: "E-mail must be a string and a true e-mail "
          },

   Phone: {
           bsonType: "string",
           pattern:"^(0|\+33)[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$",
           description: "Phone must be a 10 digits french phone number, eventually using 33 format"
        },
```

then I try to insertOne document like this :

```
var db = client.db("dbName");
var testObj = {Email: "EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM", Phone: "+33606060606"};

db.collection("customers").insertOne(testObj, function(err, res) {
etc.});
```

==> It fails.

If I remove the Phone string :

```
var db = client.db("dbName");
var testObj = {Email: "EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM"};

db.collection("customers").insertOne(testObj, function(err, res) {
etc.});
```

==> It works.

If I removes the regex pattern when I create the 'customers" collection, it works.

I have tried several regex/examples all validated on online regex for Javascript testers..all fails.. :-(

Thank you for your help on this, I wish you all a very good day!

Comment: Have you tried `0606060606` as the phone number? or try double black slash in the regex `^(0|\\+33)[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$`

Comment: Hi Neverever ! Yes, not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is the regex pattern, you need to double backslash here

```
    pattern: "^(0|\\+33)[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$"
```

**Note**: 
I'm not sure how to update existing validator, so I dropped the `customers` collection and re-create with the correct validator pattern